# Screen reader supporting the load of the html cite=“” attribute

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-reader

Is there a screen reader which is able to load url of the`cite=`attribute like many do for the`longdesc=`attribute ?

If yes, how to use it for that purpose *(it’s a global claim that browsers don’t use the cite attribute but screen readers for blind people can) (I can source that if needed)* ?

I don’t care about the language, which can even be for Fula. I just need to find one which is able the`cite=`attribute.

Comment: May I ask why you reverted my change to use code markup? And why do you prefer to use Unicode’s small capital letters?

Comment: @unor : use small capitals for abbreviations. In order to stay consistent, the cite attribute is written in the same way both in text and title. The braces shouldn’t contains sentences.

Comment: I think the drawbacks of using small caps Unicode chars on this site are bigger than the (arguable) typographical advantage, namely that it doesn’t work in the browser search (Ctrl + f) unless you’d actually type the small cap chars, and that users of search engines like Google or DuckDuckGo won’t be able to find all relevant questions/answers anymore (unless they’d search for both variants).

Comment: @unor neither of your previous assumptions are correct.

Comment: I created a [discussion on Meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/small-capital-characters-in-posts) -- I’m looking forward to read your stance and why my assumptions aren’t correct.

Comment: I've edited this to not use the small-caps characters. Please, feel free to weigh in [on meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/small-capital-characters-in-posts) with your thoughts on the subject. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a screen reader which is able to load url of thecite=attribute like many do for thelongdesc=attribute ?

I have a reasonable understanding of how screen reader software processes HTML semantics. To my knowledge the majority of SR software does nothing with the `cite` attribute.

The JAWS screen reader does [announce the `cite` attribute](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2011/03/html5-accessibility-chops-section-elements/) value when it is present on a `blockquote` element, but it does not provide navigation to the URL.

Comment: Did you investigated rarely supported languages ?